# Setting listeners on buttons in a ListView populated by a CursorAdapter from a Fragment

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments

Although a developer for more years than I can remember  I'm new to Java/Android and the whole OOP thing... Yes we do still exist... shambling relics of a more sequential age...!!
Anyway I have a fragment which invokes a CursorAdapter to populate a ListView.

The ListView has several TextViews and two buttons on each row.

I have been trying to set up listeners on each of the buttons so far without success...
 I've searched this forum (and others) and I've used  several bits of code suggested by contributors..

From my research my biggest problem seems to be that I'm doing all this from a Fragment.

My question is how do I pass the base ListView id from the Fragment to the Adapter...???

My ListView Child XML...

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="60dp">


<TextView
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/textViewMarginTop"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/textViewMarginRight"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="12345678"
    android:id="@+id/job_id"

    />

<TextView
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/textViewMarginTop"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="abcdef"
    android:id="@+id/from_location"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/job_id"


    />

<TextView
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/textViewMarginTop"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Blanchardstown"
    android:id="@+id/to_location"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/from_location"

    />
<Button
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/job_bid"
    android:text="@string/joblist_bid"
    android:layout_below="@+id/job_id"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/job_details"
    />
<Button
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/job_details"
    android:text="@string/joblist_details"
    android:layout_below="@+id/to_location"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

---

My ListView Parent XML

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="60dp">


<TextView
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/textViewMarginTop"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/textViewMarginRight"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="12345678"
    android:id="@+id/job_id"

    />

<TextView
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/textViewMarginTop"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="abcdef"
    android:id="@+id/from_location"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/job_id"


    />

<TextView
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/textViewMarginTop"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Blanchardstown"
    android:id="@+id/to_location"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/from_location"

    />
<Button
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/job_bid"
    android:text="@string/joblist_bid"
    android:layout_below="@+id/job_id"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/job_details"
    />
<Button
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/job_details"
    android:text="@string/joblist_details"
    android:layout_below="@+id/to_location"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

---

My Fragment Code

---

```
public class jobListFragment extends ListFragment
{
private final String m_LogcatTag = "assignment5";


public ListView m_jobListView;
public JobDataAdpter m_jobDataAdapter;
JobsDataSource m_datasource;
private SQLiteDatabase m_database;
CursorAdapter m_cursoradaptor;
public View m_jobListFragmentBaseView;

 Cursor m_cursor;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,   Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

     m_jobListFragmentBaseView = inflater.inflate(layout.joblistfragment, container, false);


    ListView m_jobListView = (ListView)m_jobListFragmentBaseView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);


    //Declare an object to handle database I-O and open a channel to the database

    m_datasource = new JobsDataSource (getActivity().getApplicationContext());


    m_datasource.open();


    m_cursor = m_datasource.getAllJobs();


    m_jobDataAdapter = new JobDataAdpter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), m_cursor, 0);


    m_jobListView.setAdapter(m_jobDataAdapter);



    return m_jobListFragmentBaseView;

}
```

---

My Adapter Code

---

```
public class JobDataAdpter extends CursorAdapter
{
private final String mLogcatTag = "assignment5";
 protected ListView mListView;               THIS IS THE VARIABLE IN QUESTION

public JobDataAdpter(Context context, Cursor cursor, int flags )

{
    super(context, cursor, 0);

}

protected static class RowViewHolder
{
    public TextView m_job_bid;
    public TextView m_job_details;
}
//End New Code\

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent)
{

 View view = View.inflate(context, R.layout.jobslistlayout, null);


 RowViewHolder holder = new RowViewHolder();
 holder.m_job_bid = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.job_bid);
 holder.m_job_details = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.job_details);

 holder.m_job_bid.setOnClickListener(m_OnBidClickListener);
 holder.m_job_details.setOnClickListener(m_OnDetailsClickListener);

 view.setTag(holder);

 return view;
 }


@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor)
{

    TextView m_job_IdView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.job_id);
    TextView m_from_LocationView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.from_location);
    TextView m_to_LocationView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.to_location);

    // Extract properties from cursor
    long row_id = cursor.getLong((cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MySQLiteOpenHelper.m_COLUMN_ID)));
    String m_job_id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MySQLiteOpenHelper.m_COLUMN_JOB_ID));
    String m_From_Location = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MySQLiteOpenHelper.m_COLUMN_JOB_FROM_LOCATION));
    String m_To_Location = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MySQLiteOpenHelper.m_COLUMN_JOB_TO_LOCATION));

    // Populate fields with extracted properties

    m_job_IdView.setText(m_job_id);
    m_from_LocationView.setText(String.valueOf(m_From_Location));
    m_to_LocationView.setText(String.valueOf(m_To_Location));
}

private View.OnClickListener m_OnBidClickListener = new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {                        HERE IS WHERE THE VARIABLE IS USED
        final int position = mListView.getPositionForView((View) v.getParent());
        Log.v(mLogcatTag, "Title clicked, row %d"  + position);
    }
};

private View.OnClickListener m_OnDetailsClickListener = new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        final int position = mListView.getPositionForView((View) v.getParent());
        Log.v(mLogcatTag, "Text clicked, row %d" + position);
    }
};

}
```

---

OK guys .....That's it.... Hope you can help

Comment: You need to condense the question down, because as it stands it's not clear what you're asking and instead have just dumped a bunch of code. Please try to have a reproducible minimal test case and state your question clearly.

Comment: @AlBlue I understand that this forum is for developers of all level of experience. I don’t have sufficient frame of reference to be sure I’m asking the correct question which led me to “just dump a bunch of code” in order to provide the context for a “reproducible minimal test case”.  Is "how do I pass the base ListView id from the Fragment to the Adapter" not stating the question clearly? I have found that contributors to this forum give their time to those, such as myself, without demeaning questioners. Perhaps, as someone of great experience in this area, you might offer me some guidance?